# Losing changs during github stages, commit and push to the repository

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

Iam using git and github with vscode,
I stashed changes , committed them and pushed them into my repository, using push to.
All the steps had done without any git command in terminal,

My problem is all my changs have not showing on the repository and my new changs had deleted from vscode.

Why this happening?
can i restore  my changs into vscode?
I make the same steps everytime and i never faced this problem,

Could any one explain what happened and  helps me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe i had said it wrong , but i clicked on the plus button then i put my massage then i committed the changs and i always used to click on 3 dot on the sidebar and went to push to ,then , chose the repository name

Comment: This a little confusing but the simplest thing might be to open up the terminal within vscode and try `git status`?  this should tell if you have any commits waiting to be pushed up or if anything has been modified.